# DIV margin not working

Tags: html, css

Anybody tell me what is problem with the following code.
Left and top margins on `.middle` do not work.

I worked a lot but could not found any problem with the code below.

Please observe `.middle` class and `div` on which `.middle` is applied.

```css
.container {
  height: 48px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.left {
  margin-left: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 4px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
}
.middle {
  margin-left: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}
.right {
  margin-left: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40%;
}
.button {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 6px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-color: #333;
}
p {
  color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
    <button class="button">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is primarily due to **collapsing margins**.

With regard to the top margin, in effect it is still there but it is spilling out of `.container`. To fix add `overflow: auto;` to `.container` to stop margin collapsing.

The second is due to `.left` being floated. To add the `margin` to the left of `.middle` you can either:

- Use `calc(30% + 12px)` ((`width` of `.left`) + (`margin` of `.left`) + (`margin` of `.middle`))
- Add `margin-right: 6px;` to `.left` as floated element `margin`s do not collapse *Thanks to @Alohci for this suggestion*

```css
.container {
  height: 48px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
.left {
  margin-left: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 4px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
}
.middle {
  margin-left: calc(30% + 12px);
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}
.right {
  margin-left: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40%;
}
.button {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 6px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-color: #333;
}
p {
  color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">
    <button class="button">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this is by far the best answer here, the `overflow:hidden` on the .middle div means that it *is* aware of the floats' existence. However the CSS rules here say that the border box of the .middle div must not overlap with the margin box of the float. The solution for the horizontal margin, if you don't want to use calc(), is to make use of the asymmetry and put a right margin of 6px on the left float, instead of a left margin on the .middle div.

Comment: Good spot @Alohci, I've modified the answer to avoid confusion and added your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't set a `width` and `float` for the middle div. One work around would be to add position:relative and replace `margin-top` and `margin-left` with `top` and `left`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rqLb7m4a/

Comment: Its ok but how to ad 6px margin on right side of the green div also?

Comment: If you need the 6px space, add a width to the div (ie 30% - margin of the left div - margin of the middle div - left and right margins of the right div) which becomes (30% - 6px - 6px -12px) =  (30% - 24px). 

I've used calc to set this width. See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rqLb7m4a/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention width, some time width auto will not work and also give float: left; property to middle div.
And you can code div's like left, midile and right

```
  <div class="left"> </div>
  <div class="middle"> </div>
  <div class="right">  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add **float:left** to the middle element and **set** the **width** to a value.

But here i think you want this div to take all the width that it can, right ?

I think it's time to use **flexbox** :
http://jsfiddle.net/w16cq27x/

```
 .container {
     height: 48px;
     width: 80%;
     background-color: #999;
     margin: 0 auto;
     display:flex;
 }
```